# Login issue after logging out

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm currently working on a login page for my website and I'm using PHP. 
When I try to login for the first time, it works just fine, passwords are verified correctly, it shows an error if the password doesn't match or if the user is not registered first (email address not found), so I'm thinking the code logic is fine.

When I logout and try to login again, the code doesn't work as it should, I'm just redirected to the login page regardless if I type the password right or wrong or if the email address exists. Everything works fine again after I close the tab and reopen it.

I think it may be a session issue but I'm still new to this so I hope you can help me.

This is the logout code (edited):

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <?php
    session_cache_expire();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header ('Location: home.php');
  ?>
</html>
```

Login:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}   
var_dump($_SESSION);
if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
require('dbconnect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Business Bridge </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h2> Logge Dich ein </h2>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['login'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $statement ->bindParam(1,$email);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $res = $statement->fetch();
        $data = $res[1] ."\n" . $res[2] . "\n";
        if($statement->rowCount() > 0 ) {
            if (password_verify($passwort, $res[2]) && $email == $res[1]){
                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                $_SESSION['vname'] = $_POST['vname'];
                $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $res[6];
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $res[0];
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
            else{
                echo "Falsches Passwort, probiere es noch einmal!";
            }
        }else{ 
            echo "Die Email Addresse gibt es nicht!";
        }
        }

    ?>
            <form action="?login=1" method="post">
                E-Mail: <br> <input type="email" size="40" maxlength="250" 
                name="email"><br><br>
            Dein Passwort:<br> <input type="password" size="40"  
                maxlength="250" name="passwort"><br><br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$pdo->connection = null;
?>
```

Edit: The problem was caused by a false redirection. The logout code would redirect to a different login page.

Comment: *"Everything works fine again after I close the tab and reopen it."*  - http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score -1):

```
 //Try this one in your logout.php page

    <?php
         session_start();
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <body>

   <?php
 // remove all session variables
    session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
     session_destroy(); 
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more of an explanation of what this does, where exactly to put it, and why it will help?

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work. Thank you for your answer though :)

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.